# Remote being automatically added in main project folder

Tags: github

this is my problem.

1. I create a new directory and set the remote to my new repo on GitHub
2. I add and stage my files
3. I push my files up but it **adds all my other folders from another directory**

When I push my files up from a new directory it is  **adding that remote to my main** and **pushing my files up from my main directory.** I subsequently REMOVE the remote added in my main directory. However, it keeps on re-adding the remote to my main everytime I create a new directory, create the new remote and push files up.

I honestly have tried almost every command to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

I was forgetting to run 'git init' :facepalm